# Trouble returning early resolve in promises in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a function in which further execution is decided within the function itself. Need to use promises as it is an asynchronous function. The problem is that it continues execution even  after resolve.

My Code :

```
function initApp () {
    token = getToken () ;
    if ( token == null ) {
        resolve ('Not Found') ;
    } else {
        // ... async process
        if ( tokenStatus == "true" ) {
            resolve ('Welcome') ;
        } else {
            resolve ('Invalid') ;
        }
    }
}

let init = new Promise ( ( resolve , reject ) => { 
    initApp ();
});

init.then((successMessage) => {
    alert ( successMessage ) ;
}
```

I am getting a undefined resolve error. Also , earlier when I hadn't used else , it continued execution even after encountering resolve. What should be the proper way to do this?

Comment: you do realise `let init =` is clobbering `function init` right?

Comment: perhaps [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLwL424n/) helps - I've added some extra lines so you get paid more - seriously though https://jsfiddle.net/dLwL424n/1/ may help, but I smell issues with `//async process` followed by synchronous test of `tokenStatus`

Comment: Nothing like that man ;-)

Comment: I'm pulling your chain :p but see the updated fiddle - I suspect you still will have issues as mentioned

Comment: BTW , in actual function , it is initApp

Comment: your code example should be as close to "working" as you can make it :p

Comment: Now, serious problem with your code ... resolve/reject are only in scope inside the promise constructor for `init` - you can't use them in `initApp` (unless you pass them as an argument, but that makes the code look very odd - answer below is good, and addresses the `//async process` issue I was worried about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resolve` and `reject` are undefined in your function because they are out of scope. You should instead return a Promise from your init function, like so:

```
function init () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let token = getToken()
    if (!token) {
      reject('not found')
    } else {
      doSomethingAsync((tokenStatus) => {
        if (!tokenStatus) return reject('Invalid')
        resolve('Welcome')
      })
    }
  })
}

init().then((successMsg) => {
  alert(successMsg)
}).catch((errMsg) => {
  alert(errMsg)
})
```

You're also not using Promises correctly. You should `resolve` when what you're trying to do is *successful*, and `reject` when what you're trying to do has failed. A takeaway for you my friend is to read up up on Promises as well as the basic parts of JavaScript (e.g you're overwriting the `init` function with a variable later on). Additionally, you should look into async & await which makes asynchronous code read more synchronously.

Comment: `look into async & await which makes asynchronous code read more synchronously` - the problem with this is ... Promises can be polyfilled to work in old browsers (i.e. Internet Exploder) - using async/await would require transpiling ... an additional complication for not that much benefit (in this scenario)

Comment: @JaromandaX I understand your concern, but I'll leave that decision up to the user who asked the question. I'm just here to put him on the right track.

Comment: Thanks bro helped a lot. Though could you please elaborate about the problem reported in the comment above.

Comment: @SamagraSinghTomar Not all web browsers and their versions has support for the latest JavaScript language features. To solve this, you can polyfill *certain* features like `Promise` if it does not exist, but not all features can be polyfilled either. If that is the case, a transpilation step is required using something like Babel to "transpile" the "modern" source code to "older" source code so that it works. Source code that uses `async/await` features gets transpiled to regular callback-style asynchronosity. See [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=await) and [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)